# How to use :s with regex and filename in vim

Tags: vim, macros, escaping, remap

Wanting to create a function which will add me python logger at each function define I came up on macro:

```
nnoremap <leader>L :%s/\(\s*\)def \(\w\S*\)\(self.*\):/\0\r\1\tlogging.info(\'\2)\')/g<cr>
```

It works, but I need eddited filename too, so I added to macro: `in \=expand("%p")`. Now macro looks like that:

```
nnoremap <leader>L :%s/\(\s*\)def \(\w\S*\)\(self.*\):/\0\r\1\tlogging.info(\' \=expand("%p") \2)\')/g<cr>
```

Which doesn't work, because it prints whole `=expand("%p")` as a text, not as a file name.

It seems to me that in general in text substitution I can use expand if I do not use regex.

I would be terribly grateful for correct macro and explanation why didn't it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
nnoremap <leader>L :%s/\(\s*\)def \(\w\S*\)\(self.*\):/\=substitute(submatch(0),submatch(0),'&\r'.submatch(1).'\tlogging.info('''.expand("%p").' '.submatch(2).''')','g')/<cr>
```

---

> `4.2 Substitute                                          *:substitute*`
>                                                               `*:s* *:su*`
>
> :[range]s[ubstitute]/{pattern}/**{string}**/[flags] [count]
>
> ```
>                                     *sub-replace-special* *:s\=*
> ```
>
> When the **{string} starts with "\="** it is **evaluated** as an **expression**,
>   see |sub-replace-expression|.  You can use that for complex
>   replacement or special characters.

`\=` if it is used **inside** the **{string}**(i.e **not at the begining**) it will be taken **literally**(i.e **not** as a s**pecial character**)

Comment: It's nearly perfect! it only have an issue with *, with the erro on functions with * and ** args:
E871: (NFA regexp) Can't have a multi follow a multi !
E61: Nested *

Comment: Can you provide an example of line that you want to change and the result ?

Comment: Sure, it would be: `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):`

Comment: and the final result ? :)

Comment: It doesn't work on this line at all - so none :) I'll post it in comment if I manage to solve it.

Comment: I just want you to write what do you want to get. great !